# Facebook Graph Bad Request 400 PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

graph.facebook.com suddenly returns 400.

I call graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=[at] to get user´s profile in order to validate the user's indentity.

This was working perfectly, but now it's not. Do you guys know if Facebook blocks servers or something like that?

The site is hosted in a Linode Server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Facebook access tokens typically expire after 3600 seconds, which would result in error 400s.

You can extend them: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

Comment: It turns out that the token i'm using creates itself a few seconds before to the php request. :S

Answer (score 0):

i've detected something. From my production server, ping graph.facebook.com returns 31.13.73.145, but from my computer (located in Argentina) it returns 31.13.85.8.

So, i've changed the server /etc/hosts file to point to *31.13.73.145,* so it works.

Honestly it's not a solution. Still I would like to know if someone has had this problem.

Thanks!

**CORRECTION:**

I made a typo, changed /etc/hosts to 31.13.85.8 and then it worked.

Comment: That's really not likely to be it. Most large websites have many IPs - if you ping Google, Yahoo, Facebook, Amazon, etc. from different locations you'll get different IPs. They do this to point you at their nearest datacenter / CDN edge to you.